# Split a separated value to new single column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I want to separate the `|` delimited string into new column, I tried the below code but I think is not a good practice.

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE(SUBSTRING(ReferenceName, 1, CHARINDEX('|', ReferenceName)), '|', '') AS CreditCard, 
    ReferenceName
FROM  
    CTS.DBO.cts_TxSalesPayment
```

[image]

**Expected result**

Split the value based on the delimiter:

```
CardNumber | ExpiryDate | ApprovalCode | .... | ... | ... | ...
```

Comment: If you had a variable number of fields, then you should look for another solution. Given than you seem to know how many fields you want to extract from the string, what you have done is the best way to do this. What seems like bad practice is that you are working with data like this in SQL, but that's probably as the result of an import from another file format. You should import the data into a proper relational table & query against that if possible. Avoid having non-atomic fields as the norm.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a REPLACE function to allow the column to be parsed as XML, then PIVOT the result.

For example:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ReferenceName VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @T VALUES ('CardNumber=asdf|ExpiryDate=1234124x|ApprovalCode=aaaaa'), ('CardNumber=zzz|ExpiryDate=123|ApprovalCode=q'), ('CardNumber=zzz|ExpiryDate=111|ApprovalCode=q2');

SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT RN, colName = A.B.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(max)'), colVal = A.B.value('@val', 'varchar(max)')
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), col = CAST('<' + REPLACE(REPLACE(ReferenceName, '=', ' val='''), '|', '''/><') + ''' />' AS XML)
        FROM @T
    ) AS T
    CROSS APPLY col.nodes('*') AS A(B)
) AS T
PIVOT
(
    MAX(colVal) FOR colName IN ([CardNumber], [ExpiryDate], [ApprovalCode])
) AS P;
```

Comment: Dude, this is technically brilliant. I bow to your understanding of XML in SQL Server. But in this case it's like building a particle accelerator to boil water. What the OP is already doing is simple, intuitive, readable, and performant. And using the XML methods for string manipulation is also a bit of a hack. It's about time SQL Server got proper RegEx support.